# Example of iPad SplitView where there is an .xib file specified for Root Controller?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Is it possible to specify a xib file for the RootController of an iPad's splitview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the MainWindow-iPad.xib that is autogenerated with your project.  You should be able to expand the SplitViewController to display the viewControllers that are housed in it.  You'll notice that the Detail side says something about "Loaded by DetailViewController.xib".  You'll have to click the RootViewController icon and specify a nib name and make the necessary connections in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you found an answer already, but for folks who are reading this and want a good source, the Apple Sample COde "MultipleDetailView" uses a SplitView that goes to new nibs for the RootController...just use that as a guide!